# Flyway command line: Invalid argument: -placeholders

Tags: database, deployment, command-line, database-migration, flyway

What is the exact syntax required to pass a placeholder to flyway command line?

I have attempted to add a placeholder to my flyway command line migrate but getting exceptions when calling it. 
I have been back to the documentation several times re-checking syntax/case/etc but cannot spot what I am doing wrong here.

It looks something like this

`flyway -url="jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<database>" -user=<user> -password=<pwd> -placeholders.abc=123 migrate -X`

And I get this exception

````
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Invalid argument: -placeholders
        at org.flywaydb.commandline.CommandLineArguments.validate(CommandLineArguments.java:183)
        at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:86)```
````

Comment: Is the issue 123? I bet it isn't allowed to start with a number.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out on windows that I needed to enclose the placeholders in double quotes.

`flyway -url="jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<database>" -user=<user> -password=<pwd> "-placeholders.abc=123" migrate -X`